# Set puTTY title to open file

Tags: vim, putty

I think this might be impossible, but is there a way to set the title of a puTTY window to the file that vim has opened? All my windows just say vim right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In vim issue `:set title` and make sure that PuTTY is not blocking the remote changing of tilte: `Properties` -> `Terminal` -> `Features` -> `Disable remote-controlled window title changing`.